# How can i get PrimaryKey value for newly inserted row in SQL which should work on all SQL libraries

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, qt, sqlite

**This question has been asked many times but I never got correct answer because of following complications :**

First solution is to use SQL library/server dependant solution like getlastrowid(), SCOPE_IDENTITY() etc. but I want solution to work on all SQL implementations at least on following SQLite, MSSQL, MYSQL, PSQL. even if I manage to use different function for each implementation of SQL I got this problem, whenever there are triggers on table on which row is being inserted that trigger inserts rows too, above functions returns ID for row inserted by trigger.

Second solution is simple I can just use transaction and in transaction after inserting row I can just call SELECT max(ID) from table which will give ID of newly inserted row and because transaction is used it will be correct ID even if other connections has been trying to get new ID at same time. problem with this is that table will be locked and if connection is bad it could be locked for long time.
Third one is to use GUUID instead but I read on many forums that using it not a good idea.

I am using Qt 5.2 to develop database app.
so i would like to know if there are any other ways on how i can get ID of newly inserted row to use as foreign key for next row insert.
I would also like to know using transaction really blocks all other connections from accessing that table though i know that SQLite does block all other connections but would like to know about MSSQL, MYSQL, PSQL.

Comment: So any other alternative to add transaction data to master?

Comment: He never stated he used PHP for this.

Answer (score 2):

You could use Qt `lastInsertId()` function : http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qsqlquery.html#lastInsertId, that is if you use QSqlQuery to perform your query.

Comment: Was thinking about using this same function but I am not sure if it will work with trigger which insert more rows too.

Comment: If it doesn't work, I'd suggest to write a function which will run a different query depending on the SQL engine used, this way you'll be able to use statement returning the id (like `RETURNING` in Postgresql), and you'll be sure that it is the id inserted.

Comment: It should work with a trigger, it would only return the first inserted entry's ID.

Comment: I did some checks with lastInsertId() and it does work with AFTER, BEFORE Trigger but doesn't work if used on Instead Of trigger in SQLite. seems like I have to avoid using Instead of trigger though I needed this trigger to manipulate data before inserting/ conditionally inserting data. if you know any other option to do this do tell or I just have to do that in APP itself.